# Property of symmetric complex matrices

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, proof-explanation, symmetric-matrices

I'm not sure if I should post my question here or on Physics Stackexchange, but this is a question on a matrix property often seen in quantum physics textbooks (eg. Altland and Simons' *Condensed Matter Field Theory*).

> If we have some (positive) matrix $A$, then in order to make it symmetric
>   we apply the relation
>
> $$x_i A_{ij} x_j \equiv x^T A x = \tfrac{1}{2} [x^T (A+A^T) x]$$

**Question:** Is this relation true for both real and complex matrices $A$? If $A$ is complex do we need to instead use the Hermitian matrix in the above expression, i.e.

$$x^T A x = \tfrac{1}{2} [x^T (A+A^\dagger) x]?$$

Comment: To make it symmetric, add the transpose. To make it Hermitian, add the complex conjugate of the transpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $$x^T A x = \frac{1}{2} x^T (A + A^T) x $$
is true for complex vectors and matrices too.  However, complex symmetric matrices do not have particularly nice properties.  Hermitian matrices are
more useful, but there the equation is

$$ x^\dagger A x = \frac{1}{2} x^\dagger (A + A^\dagger) x $$

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why complex symmetric matrices don't have very  nice properties?

Comment: For example, $\pmatrix{2i & 1\cr 1 & 0\cr}$ is not diagonalizable.